# Apache error log with PHP errors

Tags: apache-2.2, php, logging

I just set up PHP and Apache and would like to find where the errors are going.  What is the default path of the error logs in apache for PHP?

Comment: You havent mentioned what kind of operating system you're running apache on. Check your apache config for the location of logfiles.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Which is the file that should contain this information by the way? - Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are the locations in these popular operating systems:

RHEL / Red Hat / CentOS / Fedora Linux Apache error file location - /var/log/httpd/error_log

Debian / Ubuntu Linux Apache error log file location - /var/log/apache2/error.log

FreeBSD Apache error log file location - /var/log/httpd-error.log

The detailed answer about the Apache log files is here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-logs/

Answer (score 3):

**Try this:**

1. error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
2. error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log
3. Create log file manually

```
touch /var/log/php_errors.log
chown www-data: /var/log/php_errors.log
chmod +rw /var/log/php_errors.log
```

**Now you can view PHP errors by this way**

```
    tail /var/log/php_errors.log
```

Comment: Would be useful to many more - if you could mention where to add the lines 1 and 2

Comment: #1 and #2 can be configured in several places: In php.ini (global config) or an apache virtualhost block (per website config)... or at runtime with ini_set(). That is probably why the author of this answer did not get into that particular subject.